# How to make use public variable inside function in android?

Tags: android

In android I have the following situation (not working code, just to show what I am trying to talk about):

```
public class Test extends ArrayAdapter<MyDataObject> {

    public final int number = 4;

    public Test(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // lines of code 
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.d("TESTTEST", "Number:  " + this.number);
            }
        });
        // other lines of code
        // ...
```

The variable `number` is public, but I am not able to reference its content inside of `onClick`.

Is there a simple way to use the content of the variable `number` inside the function `onClick`? Or do I need an enchilada of other and unrelated classes, functions, methods, interfaces...?

Comment: Use only `number` (without `this`) or `Test.this.number`

Comment: I need to use the initial `Test` to have the correct scope? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign number to a final variable? Just remove `this` and will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `this` keywork inside the

```
Log.d("TESTTEST", "Number:  " + number);
```

`this` have a reference to the current listener instance, not the parent class.

You can also get the `number` using:

```
Log.d("TESTTEST", "Number:  " + Test.this.number);
```

Also, `setNumber` is trying to set a value to a final variable, this will not compile until you remove the `final` from the variable declaration.

Using `this` inside the method, will work if your listener was like this:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int number = 0; // in this case you can use 'this' 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.d("TESTTEST", "Number:  " + this.number);
        }
    });
```